# How to change user object for local strategy authentication from Passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

[Example of non-modified passport app here.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)

For example, we got this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    email: String,
    password: String
  }
});
```

And we need to do this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    id: String,
    user: {
        email: String,
        password: String
    }
  }
});
```

After I did those changes, I signed up, then tried to sign in, but got this error:

```
node_modules\bcrypt-nodejs\bCrypt.js:642
throw "Incorrect arguments";
```

All entries like `local.email` was renamed into `local.user.email` in the files below:

1. routes.js
2. profile.ejs
3. user.js
4. passport.js

Comment: you should `grep` for all occurrences of `local.email` in your apps directory because this makes me feel like you're missing some.

Comment: Did you change `local.password` to `local.user.password` too?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, there is a problem, where you use `bcrypt` module and it is used just twice in the linked article:

```
// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};
```

The first one in not connected to your user schema, so I think the problem is inte second function. Did you change the variables there?